# Oracle sso error

Tags: java, windows-xp, jdeveloper

I have java project built using jdeveloper 11.1.1.2.0 in windows xp, but when i try to run this program in windows 7, this gives error like:

Oracle SSO

Response has already committed.

Please help

Comment: Post some code so we can help you. without code we can't anything.

Comment: Have you already committed the response by this point?